# much more accessible than other previously discovered subsurface water sources

Tags: comparison

Does the following involve a faulty comparison?

> This discovery in Valles Marineris highlights the feature as an intriguing place for potential human exploration in the years ahead, especially because **this water** would be much more accessible than other previously discovered subsurface **water sources**.

Comment: Why do you think so? The other water sources were **less accessible** than the newly discovered one.

Comment: The original sentence compares "water" with "water sources." A reservior is a water source. Does it make sense to compare water with a water source like a reservoir?

Comment: I suppose a reservoir could be subsurface (though most are lakes), but it is made, not discovered. The paragraph appears to be referring to natural water resources.